# Storybook UI with CSS modules and Less

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less, storybook

Is it possible to use Storybook UI with React, CSS modules and Less? Have anyone managed to configure this kind of setup?

Comment: I know that by creating a CRA react project and running the storybook command to include storybook into your react project will automatically configure storybook, react and scss compiling to work together out of the box.
You could always add a ```less loader``` in the webpack config for storybook to deal with LESS files.

There has been a discussion about LESS and storybook here: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/691

If this doesn't work (although i can't see why it wouldn't) the jump from LESS to SASS is not very great, so it might be your best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding  .storybook/webpack.config.js helped me fix the issue, with

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader'],
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        modules: true,
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same case. Resolved by adding `webpackFinal` to `.storybook/main.js` :

```
module.exports = {
    stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.[tj]s'],
    webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
        config.module.rules.push(
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    require.resolve('style-loader'),
                    {
                        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                        },
                    },
                    require.resolve('less-loader')
                ]
            },
        );
        return config;
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

With sass as example:

**Step 1**: configure webpack in main.js. You can find documentation here: https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
        // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
        // You can change the configuration based on that.
        // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

        // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
        });

        // Return the altered config
        return config;
    },
    stories: ['../stories/**/*.stories.js'],
};
```

**Step 2**: Install sass-loader
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/

**Step 3**: Create your scss files

```
@import "../stories/main.scss";

h1{color:$mediumBlue}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify your **.storybook.main.js**

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.js'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (webpackConfig, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.
    const { loadCracoConfig } = require('@craco/craco/lib/config');
    const { getCraPaths } = require('@craco/craco/lib/cra');
    const context = {env: process.env.NODE_ENV};
    const cracoConfig = loadCracoConfig(context);
    context.paths = getCraPaths(cracoConfig);
    const {overrideWebpackConfig} = require('@semantic-ui-react/craco-less');
    overrideWebpackConfig({
      context,
      webpackConfig
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return webpackConfig;
  },
};
```

This is taken from **node_modules/@craco/craco/scripts/start.js**

Answer (score 0):

localIdentName option moved in css-loader configuration so this is the new configuration.
source: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2197#issuecomment-517234086

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      use: [
        require.resolve('style-loader'),
        {
          loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: {
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
            },
          },
        },
        require.resolve('less-loader'),
      ],
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```